# norm of inverse of a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Are there any conditions in which norm of inverse of a bounded operator T is equal to reciprocal of norm of the operator T.

Comment: Answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/525970/1424. T must be a scalar multiple of an isometry.

Answer (score 0):

For example $T$ is similarity that is $||T(x)|| =s||x||$ for $x\in X.$