# Relation between operator norm of a matrix and norm of inverse

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{R}$, define the operator norm as $\|A\|: = \sup\{\|A\mathbf{x}\| : \|\mathbf{x}\|=1\}$.

If $A$ is invertible, I realize that in general we have $\|A^{-1}\|\|A\|\geq 1$.

My question:

What is a concrete example where   this inequality is strict? I can't think of one.

Comment: The question was on strict inequality.

Comment: @angryavian That question has no information on producing a strict inequality.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/525983/43949).

Comment: Try $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$  or $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & {1 \over 2} \end{bmatrix}$ .

Comment: @angryavian You're right thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$(\mathbb{R}^2, \|\cdot\|_{sup})\to(\mathbb{R}^2, \|\cdot\|_1)$ i.e. $\|(x,y)\|_1=|x|+|y|$

$A= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1\\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]=A^{-1}$

We have $\|(1,1)^{t}\|_{sup}=1$. Thus  $\|A(1,1)^{t}\|_1=\|(1,1)^{t}\|_1=2$ then $\|A\|=\|A^{-1}\|>1$. Finally $\|A\|\cdot\|A^{-1}\|>1$.

Comment: Sorry. @angryvian responded.