# Norm of Ratio of Operators

Tags: operator-theory, power-series, normed-spaces

Suppose $a(L)$ and $b(L)$ are series of negative powers of the lag operator, that is
$$a(L) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_jL^{-j},\quad\text{and}\quad b(L) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_jL^{-j}.$$ 
Also suppose that $||a(L)||<1$ with the operator norm, and suppose that $c$ is a scalar with $|c|<1$.

> Which assumption must $b(L)$ satisfy to guarantee that
>   $$\left\Vert \frac{b(L)+c}{1-a(L)} \right\Vert <1 ?$$

---

Obs: If 
$$\left\Vert \frac{b(L)+c}{1-a(L)} \right\Vert \leq \frac{|| b(L)+c||}{||1-a(L)||},$$
then it is easy to see that
$$ ||a(L)||+||b(L)||+c<1$$
would be sufficient.

---

Obs2: By 'lag operator' I mean the shift operator with a unit shift, so that $||L||=1$.

Comment: When you write $\frac{b(L) + c}{1 - a(L)}$, do you mean $[b(L) + c][1 - a(L)]^{-1}$?

Comment: Is there a difference between the two in this case?

Comment: Since we are working with operators, not real numbers, I just want to make sure what you mean by division. Therefore, I assume you take $1/T$ as $T^{-1}$. In your example, we may have also interpreted $\frac{b(L)+c}{1 - a(L)}$ to be $[1 - a(L)]^{-1}[b(L)+c]$, but since the lag operator commutes, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: But then we reach another problem: $\|T^{-1}\| \neq \|T\|^{-1}$. Indeed, $1 = \|I\| = \|TT^{-1}\| \le \|T\| \|T^{-1}\| \implies \|T^{-1}\| \ge \|T\|^{-1}$, so the inequality you present in Obs is not necessarily true.

Comment: I see what you mean. This still doesn't rule it out though, right? To be sure, I am not claiming that the Obs is correct, just that if it is I would know the answer to the original question.

Comment: I guess one condition is this: $\|[b(L) + c][1 - a(L)]^{-1}\| \le (\|b(L)\| + c)\|(1 - a(L))^{-1}\| < 1 \implies \|b(L)\| < \|(1 - a(L))^{-1}\|^{-1} - c$

Comment: Combining your result with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/526701/287326), the condition in Obs can be shown to be sufficient. If you want to write this up as an answer I would be happy to give you the bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the lag operator is commutative, we can safely read
\begin{align*}
\frac{b(L)+c}{1-a(L)} = [b(L)+c][1-a(L)]^{-1}
\end{align*}
Taking norms,
\begin{align*}
\|[b(L)+c][1-a(L)]^{-1}\| \le \|b(L)+c\|\cdot\|[1-a(L)]^{-1}\|
\end{align*}
Then, as @mzp pointed out from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525970/norm-of-an-inverse-operator-t-1-t-1/526701#526701) with $T = 1 - a(L)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\|[1-a(L)]^{-1}\| \le \frac{1}{1 -\|a(L)\|}
\end{align*}
And so
\begin{align*}
\|[b(L)+c][1-a(L)]^{-1}\| \le \frac{\|b(L)\|+c}{1 - \|a(L)\|}
\end{align*}
A sufficient condition is therefore $\frac{\|b(L)\|+c}{1 - \|a(L)\|} < 1$ or $\|b(L)\| < 1 - \|a(L)\| - c$, which is exactly the condition @mzp presents under Obs!