# Invertible operators and norms

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A$ be an invertible opeartor, $B$ being another operator, is |ABA^{-1}| \leq |B|?

Comment: Seems unlikely: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525970/norm-of-an-inverse-operator-t-1-t-1

Comment: Have you tried anything ? A random choice of two noncommuting $2\times 2$ matrices give counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

When $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, we have $ABA^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. So, $\|ABA^{-1}\| = 2 \not\leq 1 = \|B\|$.